# Accessing phpMyAdmin from remote computer - Strange GUI

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I've successfully connected to my database from a remote computer but I'm having problem getting the GUI right. This is how it looks like when I enter the domain name that points to phpMyAdmin on my server:

[image]

This is atypical path bug but I've searched and tried all these things:

Triple checked httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\phpMyAdmin"
    ServerName mydatabase.domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.mydatabase.domainname.com
    <Directory "E:\xampp\phpMyAdmin">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also tried editing phpmyadmin config file setting $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; to 'mydatabase.domainname.com' etc.

Any suggestions on what I'm might be doing wrong?